# Restrict making pcb library from board in altium

Tags: altium

Hi can anyone let me know if there is any provision to make user not to extract the library from the given board file in altium designer as i would not want the user to extract the footprints from my board file

Comment: Give them only the Gerber files then, not the editable files. It's a bit pointless anyway, it's easy to make your own footprints.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but i should share my board files to the vendor but still i just dont want them to extract the files from the file . so i just wanted to know if such option exists

Comment: Why would a pcb manufacturer need the whole files and not just the gerbers, that makes no sense. anyways what secrets do those footprints have that you can't let anyone see them?

Comment: @PlasmaHH might be an NDA thing. Anyway, you're right – no board house in this world prefers altium files over properly generated gerbers. And gerbers don't contain something like this. Feels like OP isn't telling us the whole story, a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but im not going to send the board for fabrication but want to send the file for some updation to vendor. So i just dont want them to acess the footprints during this

Comment: Why would you want to send them the board files? It's not quite like sharing source code, but it's unnecessary and the files are much larger, so why do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way (as far as I know) to lock out the footprints if you give a third party the full design in Altium. By giving someone the raw design files, it implicitly means you are giving them full access to the design. If this is anticipated to be a problem, then you should have a proper contract in place to address this.

If you just wish to share the physical form of a design with a partner, then the Gerber files and 3D models would be sufficient.

Having said this, footprints are trivial to copy and create so don't expect this to be any protection from someone copying the design. If someone is determined to copy your design, this is a tiny time expenditure in the wider effort.